# How can I add conditions in Doctrine for MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, document, entities

I have the Document CompetitionsDocument like this...

| Name | Position |
| --- | --- |
| Carl | Center |
| Carl | First |
| Carl | Last |
| Carl | Last |
| Mariah | Center |
| Mariah | Center |
| Mariah | Last |
| Mariah | Last |

I would like to get a grouped table like this...

| Name | First | Center | Last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carl | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Mariah | 0 | 2 | 2 |

**Used tools**:

- Symfony 4.4
- Doctrine for MongoDB
- MongoDB

My code is like this...

```
$builder->group()
    ->field('id')
    ->expression(
        $builder->expr()->field('name')->expression('$name')
    )
    ->field('first')
    ->sum(
        $builder->redact()->cond(
            $builder->expr()->gte('$position', 'First'), 1, 0
        )
    )
    ->field('center')
    ->sum(
        $builder->redact()->cond(
            $builder->expr()->gte('$position', 'Center'), 1, 0
        )
    )
    ->field('last')
    ->sum(
        $builder->redact()->cond(
            $builder->expr()->gte('$position', 'Last'), 1, 0
        )
    );
```

But I don't know how to add conditions that add 1 or 0 depending on the value.

**Note**: The function gte() returns error. I can't use 0 or 1 in the second and third parameter. I should use '$$PRUNE' or '$$DESCEND'

Comment: Use $sum to count the number of matching documents.

Comment: It returns 8 because it sums all grouped rows. But I need that add 1 to **row.first** when **position="first"**, add 1 to **row.center** when **position="center"** and add 1 to **row.last** when **position="last"**. Example first row: **{ name: 'Carl', first: 1, center: 1, last: 2 }**

Comment: If you have a question about the aggregation pipeline I suggest you ask it using mongo shell only.

Comment: @D.SM I don't know how to do that. Tell me how do I do it?